# I am currently working on Turbo c++ to be precise on c language

Tags: turbo-c++, gets

This is my program code:

[image]

and the desired output is this (copied from https://www.javatpoint.com/c-gets-puts):

[image]

and the output I am receiving is this

[image]

I would be very pleased if anybody can highlight my mistake.
Program Used: Turbo c++

Comment: Welcome ! We are here to help you, but could you please help us too? Firstly, please post you code as text, no a picture. And your output too. It's always best if you tell us 1) what the program should be doing 2) what it actually is doing 3) any error output, which you have done, so that is excellent. Please update your question and you will very quickly get an an answer. Again, welcome :-)

Comment: `%c` is the format specifier for a single `char`, not an pointer to an array thereof, which is what a C string is. You can check documentation to find it what the correct format specifier is. I vote to close as a typo. Also, you should consider updating to a modern compiler and version of C, wherein `main()` returns `int` and `conio.h` shouldn't be used.

Comment: Lolx! You just put into a comment what I was busy putting into a longer answer, saying pretty much the same (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Change `printf("You entered %c", s);` to `printf("You entered %s", s);`

Read [this page](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html) and see why it needs to be `%s` and not `%c`.

Good luck with your learning.

Btw, when you have a (larger) program which is working with no errors, you can post it on our [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site, and experienced coders will help you to improve it.

Also, I loved Turbo C++, probably before you were born ;-)  but, please visit [Software Recommendations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and ask us to recommend a good development environment for you. It is very important that you get a good IDE, with an in-built debugger - the debugger is your best friend. Turbo C has one, it's just that the whole thing is ... almost as old as me :-/  Nothing wrong with it. It works. But other (free) stuff can make your life much, much easier, and will also get you more support and not so many use Turbo C nowadays.